# Token signature invalid error

Tags: java, jwt

I've this error thrown

> com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.SignatureVerificationException: The Token's Signature resulted invalid when verified using the Algorithm: HmacSHA256

```
private static String SECRET = "some secret...";

public static DecodedJWT verify(String token) throws JWTVerificationException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(SECRET))
            .withIssuer("auth0")
            .acceptLeeway(1)
            .acceptExpiresAt(5 * 60)
            .build();

    return verifier.verify(token);
}
```

Is there some problem with the secret, on the website jwt.io I click on the secret base 64 encoded then it turns blue.

I tried encoding my secret in base 64 using https://www.base64encode.net but same problem. please advise.

Comment: can you share the secret?

Comment: yes `zZrq0sZK1yt9RJk51RTJ/jeU6WERbvr8nqKMWQJRX1E=`

Comment: I get invalid signature on jwt.io

Comment: prese the base 64 encoded check box on the right bottom side

Comment: got it, can you share an example of the token?

Comment: could it be that your token simply expired by the time you've tried verifying it?

Comment: `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0aWQiOiJiZWJlMjM4Zi1iMGM4LTQwYzMtOTYyMC1jZDRlOGUyMzIwZGMiLCJvaWQiOiI5MjJjMmZiNC0zNWI1LTExZDctOWE2NC0wMGIwZDBmY2I5ZTMiLCJzdWIiOiI5MjJjMmZiNC0zNWI1LTExZDctOWE2NC0wMGIwZDBmY2I5ZTMiLCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAdGVzdC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1MTg0NDk5NzYsImV4cCI6MTUxODQ1MzU3NiwibmJmIjoxNTE4NDQ5OTc2fQ.6InknrU67g_HEkaLxD9Ul5vOzbYGf54mJNcSyPr-xek`

Comment: is there a step required to encode base 64 as per the check box on the website?

Comment: for information I'm not the issuer of the token, all I'm doing is verifying and getting the payload out of it, and wondering what step am I missing here?

Comment: I re-login to get a new token but still not success

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [javadoc](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt/blob/7dcea427df1db2b948911e70aef2e9d7f0b7cfad/lib/src/main/java/com/auth0/jwt/algorithms/Algorithm.java#L171-L178) says you need to provide raw secret value.
That means you need to `base64`-decode the value you currently have:

```
import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.JWTVerificationException;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class JwtVerification {

    private static final String SECRET = "zZrq0sZK1yt9RJk51RTJ/jeU6WERbvr8nqKMWQJRX1E=";

    public static DecodedJWT verify(String token) throws JWTVerificationException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(Algorithm.HMAC256(Base64.getDecoder().decode(SECRET)))
                .withIssuer("auth0")
                .acceptLeeway(1)
                .acceptExpiresAt(5 * 60)
                .build();

        return verifier.verify(token);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final String token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0aWQiOiJiZWJlMjM4Zi1iMGM4LTQwYzMtOTYyMC1jZDRlOGUyMzIwZGMiLCJvaWQiOiI5MjJjMmZiNC0zNWI1LTExZDctOWE2NC0wMGIwZDBmY2I5ZTMiLCJzdWIiOiI5MjJjMmZiNC0zNWI1LTExZDctOWE2NC0wMGIwZDBmY2I5ZTMiLCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAdGVzdC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1MTg0NDk5NzYsImV4cCI6MTUxODQ1MzU3NiwibmJmIjoxNTE4NDQ5OTc2fQ.6InknrU67g_HEkaLxD9Ul5vOzbYGf54mJNcSyPr-xek";
        System.out.println(verify(token));
    }
}
```

I currently get this exception, but it looks like a problem with the token itself:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.InvalidClaimException: The Claim 'iss' value doesn't match the required one.
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.assertValidStringClaim(JWTVerifier.java:424)
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.verifyClaims(JWTVerifier.java:382)
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.verify(JWTVerifier.java:355)
    at com.swiftkey.parametron.data.JWT2.verify(JWT2.java:23)
    at com.swiftkey.parametron.data.JWT2.main(JWT2.java:28)
```

Indeed, the token does not specify `iss` field, but the verifier expects it to be "auth0" because of `.withIssuer("auth0")`.

If you look inside the token:

```
        final String token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0aWQiOiJiZWJlMjM4Zi1iMGM4LTQwYzMtOTYyMC1jZDRlOGUyMzIwZGMiLCJvaWQiOiI5MjJjMmZiNC0zNWI1LTExZDctOWE2NC0wMGIwZDBmY2I5ZTMiLCJzdWIiOiI5MjJjMmZiNC0zNWI1LTExZDctOWE2NC0wMGIwZDBmY2I5ZTMiLCJlbWFpbCI6InRlc3RAdGVzdC5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1MTg0NDk5NzYsImV4cCI6MTUxODQ1MzU3NiwibmJmIjoxNTE4NDQ5OTc2fQ.6InknrU67g_HEkaLxD9Ul5vOzbYGf54mJNcSyPr-xek";
        final DecodedJWT decodedJwt = JWT.decode(token);
        System.out.println("Header =  " + decodedJwt.getHeader());
        System.out.println("Algorithm =  " + decodedJwt.getAlgorithm());
        System.out.println("Audience =  " + decodedJwt.getAudience());
        decodedJwt.getClaims().forEach((k, v) -> {
            System.out.println("Claim " + k + " = " + v.asString());
        });
        System.out.println("ContentType =  " + decodedJwt.getContentType());
        System.out.println("ExpiresAt =  " + decodedJwt.getExpiresAt());
        System.out.println("Id =  " + decodedJwt.getId());
        System.out.println("Issuer =  " + decodedJwt.getIssuer());
        System.out.println("Subject =  " + decodedJwt.getSubject());
```

You will see that the `Issuer` field is `null`

```
Header =  eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9
Algorithm =  HS256
Audience =  null
Claim sub = 922c2fb4-35b5-11d7-9a64-00b0d0fcb9e3
Claim nbf = null
Claim oid = 922c2fb4-35b5-11d7-9a64-00b0d0fcb9e3
Claim exp = null
Claim iat = null
Claim tid = bebe238f-b0c8-40c3-9620-cd4e8e2320dc
Claim email = test@test.com
ContentType =  null
ExpiresAt =  Mon Feb 12 16:39:36 GMT 2018
Id =  null
Issuer =  null
Subject =  922c2fb4-35b5-11d7-9a64-00b0d0fcb9e3
```

Whoever generated that token did not specify the `Issuer` (aka `iss`) field.
Thus the verification fails, because we set up the verifier to expect `iss` equal to `auth0`.

Comment: there's an iss field but I removed it, let me try with Base64 code please

Comment: ok, one step further, next error, `The Claim 'iss' value doesn't match the required one.` the value in `iss` token is somewhat proprietary and has a value that looks like this, `https://subdomain.example.com/bebe238f-b0c8-40c3-9620-cd4e8e2320dc`

Comment: when I commented `.withIssuer("auth0")` it worked, can you please help me understand more on this `iss` and `.withIssuer`

Comment: updated the answer. Please upvote and accept it if it answers your question

Comment: thanks, what is the use of the field `issuer`, does it help to recognize between issuing parties, is it a field that can have any custom value? trying to understand what the issuer actually is?

Comment: Yes, it is there to identify who issued the token. see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1

Answer (score 0):

the issuer-field is normally an url-like value. If your auth0-domain for the app is `yourcompany.eu.auth0.com`, the issuer is most likely to be something like `https://yourcompany.eu.auth0.com/`

try changing

```java
    .withIssuer("auth0")
```

to

```java
    .withIssuer("https://yourcompany.eu.auth0.com/")
```

when creating the verifier.